# Errors with MakeXYEventLayer_management

Tags: arcpy, error-000732, error-000735

Here is the code:

```
import arcpy 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 
    
# ----- #  
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(
    r"C:\Users\Gdozier\Documents\Folder4",
    "Lab4GDB"
    )

# ----- #
#Creating XY load in - parantheses look weird but able to do so

return1 = arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(
    r"C:\Users\Gdozier\Documents\Folder4\garages.csv"
    "X",
    "Y",
    "garagePts"
    )

# ----- #
#loading in the xy points as wells as previosuly created GDB above - able to check using ArcGIS Pro (should check)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(
    return1,
    r"C:\Users\Gdozier\Documents\Folder4\Folder4GDB.gdb"
    )

# ----- #
# placing the GDB from data into the newly created GDB from avove

arcpy.Copy_management(
    r"C:\Users\Gdozier\Documents\Folder4\Campus.gdb\structures",
    r"C:\Users\Gdozier\Documents\Folder4\Lab4GDB.gdb\structures"
    )

# ----- #
# adding spatial reference (projection)
spatial_ref = arcpy.Describe(
    r"C:\Users\Gdozier\Documents\Folder4\Lab4GDB.gdb\structures").spatialReference
```

And I keep getting the error of:

```
ERROR 000732: XY Table: Dataset C:\Users\seths\Documents\Dozier\Lab4\garages.csvX does not exist or is not supported                                                                                                      pported
ERROR 000735: Layer Name or Table View: Value is required
Failed to execute (MakeXYEventLayer).
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing a comma (",") after:

`r"C:\Users\Gdozier\Documents\Folder4\garages.csv"`